# Error: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

Im currently learning Node JS and Javascript. Im trying to develop an application to read and download Mangas.

First i want to build up a Database. Here is where i encounter the problem.
When i run my program on my server which has 4GB of RAM (to fill my DB) i get the Fatal Error Javascript heap out of memory.

When i run the same program on my local computer with 8GB of RAM, everything works as its supposed to.

Here is the code where i fill up my DB with Manga Chapters.

```
function insertChapters(callback){

    sql_selectAll("Mangas", function (selectError, selectResult) {
        if(!selectError){
            selectResult.forEach(function (mangaItem, mangaIndex) {
                gin.mangafox.chapters(mangaItem.Title)
                    .then(chapters =>{

                        chapters.forEach(function (chapterItem) {
                            var Chapter = {
                                Title: chapterItem.name,
                                NR: chapterItem.chap_number,
                                URL: chapterItem.src,
                                MangaID: mangaItem.MangaID,
                                MangaName: mangaItem.Title,
                                VolumeNR: chapterItem.volume
                            };
                            sql_insertInto("Chapters", Chapter, function (insertError, insertResult) {
                            if(!insertError){
                                var insertedChapter =
                                "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                                "  Added new Chapter: " + Chapter.NR + " For: " + mangaItem.Title + "\n" +
                                "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                                callback(null,insertedChapter ,insertResult);
                            }
                            else{
                                if(insertError.code === "ER_DUP_ENTRY") {
                                    var dupEntry = "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                                                   "  Duplicate Entry: Chapter: " + Chapter.NR + " For: " + mangaItem.Title + "\n" +
                                                   "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"

                                        callback(null, dupEntry, null);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        callback(insertError, null, null);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })

                    })
                    .catch(fetchChapterError => {
                        callback(fetchChapterError, null, null);
                    })
            })
        }
        else{
            callback(selectError, null, null);
        }
    });
}`
```

I dont really know how to solve this problem, because im not sure what the problem is:

1. Is the problem simply that i dont have enough RAM in my server?
2. Do i have a problem with my code? Am i leaking memory somewhere?
3. Is it possible that my code needs that much memory?

Thank you so much in advance, i appreciate every help i can get.

EDIT:

```
function sql_selectAll(tableName, callback){
    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' + tableName + '`';
    connection.query(sql, function (err, selectAllResult) {
        callback(err, selectAllResult);
    })
}

function sql_insertInto(tableName, insertionObject, callback) {
    var sql = 'insert into ' + tableName + ' set ?';
    connection.query(sql, insertionObject, function (err, insertResult) {
        callback(err, insertResult);
    });
}
```

Comment: How many results are returned by the initial SQL query? Also, it is important to note that you are calling the `gin.mangafox.chapters` endpoint immediately for every single result from the SQL, and then waiting for all the results to come back. That's how asynchronous programming in JS works - the code keeps running while the async call waits. When you call `forEach` it will run the given function for every item immediately, not waiting for any asynchronous results to come back between calls. If you have hundreds of mangas in your DB, then you are doing hundreds of API calls simultaneously.

Comment: The initial query returns about 19.000 results and each of these 19.000 have an average of 15-20 Chapters.

Is there a better more memory friendly approach? Im still trying to get my head around asynchronus programming. 

Thank you for your fast response!

Comment: Yes, so you are doing 19000 requests to the mangafox API endpoint *simultaneously*. You are running out of memory because the program is trying to keep track of too many asynchronous requests, rather than doing them one at a time or in chunks. Have you looked into JS's async/await feature? Also, what are you using for your SQL calls? I don't recognize the methods like `sql_selectAll` and `sql_insertInto`. If those methods return promises, I can show you how you could structure your function using async/await.

Comment: I added my sql functions in my post above. They currently don't return promises. But i could change it. How would i do that though?

I am not familliar with async/await but im open for everything. 

Would you be able to show me what you have in mind? :)
Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Check out my answer, I think that should help out a bit. It calls the chapters endpoint one at a time rather than in batches, so it could take a very long time to run. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to do batching once you understand the one at a time code. (Hint: read the MDN article on [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: One more thing: you can significantly simplify your sql functions by just passing the callbacks rather than passing anonymous functions which call the callbacks with identical arguments. For example, the last line of `sql_selectAll` can just be: `connection.query(sql, callback);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the mangafox endpoint for every SQL result simultaneously, rather than one at a time or in chunks. You can try using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for this. I'm not familiar with the sql API you are using, but assuming that the methods `sql_selectAll` and `sql_insertInto` return [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if they aren't given a callback, you can rewrite your function to something like this:

```
async function insertChapters(callback) {
    try {
        const mangas = await sql_selectAll("Mangas");
        for (const mangaItem of mangas) {
            const chapters = await gin.mangafox.chapters(mangaItem.Title);
            for (const chapterItem of chapters) {
                const Chapter = {
                    Title: chapterItem.name,
                    NR: chapterItem.chap_number,
                    URL: chapterItem.src,
                    MangaID: mangaItem.MangaID,
                    MangaName: mangaItem.Title,
                    VolumeNR: chapterItem.volume
                };
                try {
                    const insertResult = await sql_insertInto("Chapters", Chapter);
                    const insertedChapter =
                    "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                    "  Added new Chapter: " + Chapter.NR + " For: " + mangaItem.Title + "\n" +
                    "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                    callback(null, insertedChapter, insertResult);
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.code === "ER_DUP_ENTRY") {
                        const dupEntry = "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                                       "  Duplicate Entry: Chapter: " + Chapter.NR + " For: " + mangaItem.Title + "\n" +
                                       "------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                        callback(null, dupEntry, null);
                    } else {
                        throw error;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        callback(error, null, null);
    }
}
```

Notice the `await` keywords - these are allowed in `async function`s and essentially tell the JS engine to pause execution of the async function and do something else until the awaited promise resolves.

Also notice that you can use regular old fashioned `try`/`catch` blocks when handling promises using the `await` keyword! I didn't do anything special to handle the `fetchChapterError` because it will be handled by the outermost `catch` block! Also, for the insertion errors, if it's not a duplicate entry, we can just rethrow the error and let that get caught by the outermost catch block as well.

If your SQL functions do not return promises, then on Node version 8 (latest) you can use `util.promisify`:

```
const util = require('util');
sql_selectAll = util.promisify(sql_selectAll);
```

If you are not using Node 8, then you can use another `promisify` implementation (for example, check out [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html)), or you can write your own pretty easily (read the MDN article on promises).

Comment: Thank you. I will try that. You were very helpful!

Comment: @calgara12 You're welcome. Also note that `async function`s return promises automatically, so it would be much better to get rid of the function's callback argument and use `insertChapters().then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)`. Or, you could use another async function to call `try { await insertChapters() } catch (error) { /*...*/ }`. At the top level of your code however, you are probably going to need to use `then`/`catch` once, because you can only use `await` within an async function, and you want to be able to handle that async function's returned promise.